# windows phone 7 + canvas + gesture + OnDrag events + restrict panning / dragging

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one container canvas inside which I am loading a big size canvas. I am using gesture listener methods. Few methods as OnDragStarted, OnDragDelta and OnDragCompleted, I am using these methods for panning the inner (bigger size) canvas.

Issue is that I am not able to restrict panning of inner canvas, means I should be able to pan the inner canvas within the boundary of outer canvas.

How can it do that ?

Comment: I dont quite understand the question. What you essentially have is a window, the outer canvas, looking onto a larger canvas? If you know the dimensions of both canvases you could calculate the limits of movement of the inner canvas, and within the listener methods prevent movement beyond them. If you post snippets of the relevant code I could amend them to give this behaviour.

Comment: Windows Phone 7 IE9 doesn't support Drag events... You will have to use the native Silverlight/XNA/C# events

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to be able to move the inner canvas around within the outer canvas and provide limitations on how much the inner canvas can be moved.

This functionality sounds very similar to a draggable map effect. If so, are you able to adapt the map control with a custom image for panning/zooming?

To answer your specific question as I understand it though, you need to detect the current position of the inner canvas when you process your `GestureListener` or `GestureReceiver` event.

Then either stop the movement when you reach your x,y point or prevent execution of the event if it is already at that position.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is to define the Clip of your outer Canvas. The reason you need to do this is that the Canvas by default doesn't have overflow:hidden. Any child inside it which actually is bigger will be shown outside the boundary of it.

You need to set the clip for your outer Canvas like this:

```
<Canvas Width="200" Height="100">       
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100"/>
    </Canvas.Clip>
</Canvas>
```